# How to make a Container resize dynamically based on its Column's content in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

**I'm working on a Flutter application where I have a Container widget containing a Column with multiple children. I want the Container to resize itself dynamically based on the content of the Column. Currently, the Container has a fixed height, and it's causing overflow issues when the content in the Column exceeds the predefined height.**

```
import ...

class HomeScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenConsumerState();
}

class _HomeScreenConsumerState extends ConsumerState<HomeScreen> {
      ...[... ...],
      body: Padding(
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0).copyWith(bottom: 18),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18.0),
                child: Text(
                  "SXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                  style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                    color: ColorPalette.secondary,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: 25,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              CustomContainer(
                borderRadius: 25,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.5,
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.15),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [

                      SizedBox(
                        height: 100,
                        child: CustomTextFormField(
                          hintText: 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY',
                          fontSize: 16,
                          controller: controller,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**CODE FOR CUSTOM CONTAINER**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomContainer({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
    double? width,
    double? borderRadius,
    double? height,
    Color? color,
  })  : width = width ?? double.maxFinite,
        height = height ?? 50,
        color = color ?? Colors.transparent,
        borderRadius = borderRadius ?? 12;

  final Widget child;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final double borderRadius;
  final Color color;

  @override
  State<CustomContainer> createState() => _CustomContainerState();
}

class _CustomContainerState extends State<CustomContainer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: widget.width,
      height: widget.height,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: widget.color,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
          widget.borderRadius,
        ),
      ),
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

**I tried wrapping the Column present inside the CustomContainer, with Expanded Widget & Flexible widget but it gave me the following error.**

> Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
>
> The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type BoxParentData.
>
> Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
> The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a Padding widget.

Another error I encountered when I tried wrapping the CustomContainer with Expanded

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

> When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
> These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
>
> Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent.

Comment: I can't easily try your code because of those ungiven custom widgets and hidden lines

Comment: you can try using the layout builder, provide it the content and it will handle it, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html

Comment: @WhiteChoco I only hid the App Bar Code, which was irrelevant. Btw I got rid of the problem, I just had to change the hard-coded height in the CustomContainer widget, which was creating a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten rid of the problem by removing the hard-coded height inside the `CustomContainer` widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomContainer({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
    double? width,
    double? borderRadius,
    double? height, /// REMOVED THIS
    Color? color,
  })  : width = width ?? double.maxFinite,
        /// **HERE IN THIS LINE** 
        height = height ?? 50, /// **REMOVED THIS**
        color = color ?? Colors.transparent,
        borderRadius = borderRadius ?? 12;

  final Widget child;
  final double width;
  final double height; /// **REMOVED THIS**
  final double borderRadius;
  final Color color;

  @override
  State<CustomContainer> createState() => _CustomContainerState();
}

class _CustomContainerState extends State<CustomContainer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: widget.width,
      height: widget.height, /// **REMOVED THIS**
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: widget.color,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
          widget.borderRadius,
        ),
      ),
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```